# How to format XML after fetching from table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I have to format XML structure coming from following output:

```
DECLARE @cousumptionFileName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlConStr VARCHAR(1000)

SET @cousumptionFileName = 'C:\export\IDE\Consumption.xml'  -- SELECT * FROM ' + DB_NAME()+'.dbo.ReadingData
SET @sqlConStr = 'select top 10 * from  [FixedNetworkist].[dbo].[ConsumptionReading0] order by deviceid  FOR XML AUTO' 

SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlConStr + '" queryout ' + @cousumptionFileName + ' -w -T'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

The output is:

```
<Reading0 RecordId="14452573" PartitionSequence="1" DeviceId="1015" DeviceType="13" CollectorId="74045037" CollectorType="120"  Reading="0" ReadingDateTime="2019-01-21T01:15:00" PresentationInterval="15" RecordEpochTime="-599450337"/>

<Reading0 RecordId="14452859" PartitionSequence="1" DeviceId="1015" DeviceType="13" CollectorId="51000666" CollectorType="120" ChannelNumber="1" Reading="0" IntervalStatus="0" ReadingDateTime="2019-01-21T01:15:00" PresentationInterval="15" RecordEpochTime="-599450335"/>
```

I want this to be structure like to avoid the repetitive value:

```
<Reading0 PartitionSequence="1" DeviceId="1015" DeviceType="13"   ChannelNumber="1" > 
    <Readings>
        <Reading RecordId="14452573" CollectorId="74045037" Reading="0" ReadingDateTime="2019-01-21T00:29:58" RecordEpochTime="-599453037" /> 
        <Reading RecordId="14452859" CollectorId="51000666" Reading="0" ReadingDateTime="2019-01-21T00:29:58" RecordEpochTime="-599453037" /> 
    </Readings>
```

Could anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: "*i want this to be structure like to avoid the repetitive value:*" wait, is something missing on the question..?

Answer (score 0):

For your transformation consider the use of 'FOR XML EXPLICIT', instead of 'FOR XML AUTO'. Good article to read more about:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-explicit-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017

My sample data:

```
    DECLARE @Reading TABLE ( PartitionSequence int, DeviceId int, DeviceType int, ChannelNumber int,CollectorId int,RecordId int, Reading int, ReadingDateTime datetime, RecordEpochTime int)

    INSERT INTO @Reading  ( PartitionSequence, DeviceId , DeviceType, ChannelNumber,CollectorId , RecordId, Reading, ReadingDateTime, RecordEpochTime )
    VALUES 
           (1,1015,13,1,1,14452573,0,'2019-01-21T00:29:58',-599453037)
          ,(1,1015,13,1,1,51000666,0,'2019-01-21T00:29:58',-599453037)
```

Sql query:

```
    SELECT
         1 AS Tag
         ,NULL AS parent
         ,r.PartitionSequence AS [Readings!1!PartitionSequence]
         ,r.DeviceId AS [Readings!1!DeviceId]
         ,r.DeviceType AS [Readings!1!DeviceType]
         ,r.ChannelNumber AS [Readings!1!ChannelNumber]
         ,NULL AS [Reading!2!RecordId]
         ,NULL AS [Reading!2!Reading]
         ,NULL AS [Reading!2!ReadingDateTime]
         ,NULL AS [Reading!2!RecordEpochTime]
    FROM @Reading r
    UNION 
    SELECT
          2 AS Tag
         ,1 AS parent
         ,r.PartitionSequence 
         ,r.DeviceId 
         ,r.DeviceType 
         ,r.ChannelNumber

         ,r.RecordId
         ,r.Reading
         ,r.ReadingDateTime
         ,r.RecordEpochTime
    FROM @Reading r
    FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Result of the query:

```
  <Readings PartitionSequence="1" DeviceId="1015" DeviceType="13" ChannelNumber="1">
    <Reading RecordId="14452573" Reading="0" ReadingDateTime="2019-01-21T00:29:58" RecordEpochTime="-599453037" />
    <Reading RecordId="51000666" Reading="0" ReadingDateTime="2019-01-21T00:29:58" RecordEpochTime="-599453037" />
  </Readings>
```